# Trying to using HTML data attribute to match data from two databases

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have code below that renders a few products on a page. Each of these products shares the same data attribute "data-item-upc". There is also a button that is rendered for each product on the page (6 total buttons to be exact). They all share this same data-item-upc data attribute.

I am able to successfully grab the value of the data atrribute and match it to the item with the same UPC value in the second database. But for some reason only the first button works and shows the modal. Not sure whats going on. Hoping someone can help me out would really appreciate it.

```
//declare variable to store JSON data
var product_data = {};
var nutritional_data = {};

$(document).ready(function() {

      'use strict';

      //grab product data
      $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: 'path to URL',
        cache: true,
        success: function(data){
          //assign JSON to product data variable
          product_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data).replace(/"\s+|\s+"/g,'"'));

      //grab nutrional data   
      $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: 'path to URL',
        cache: true,
        success: function(json){
          //assign JSON to product data variable
          nutritional_data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json).replace(/"\s+|\s+"/g,'"'));

          //declare divs to store data
          var productDivOne = '';
          var productDivTwo = '';

          $.each(product_data, function(i, item) {
              //convert JSON strings to uppercase for comparison
              var brandLetter = item.itemBrandLetter.toUpperCase();
              var foodService = item.itemDeli.toUpperCase();
              var brandItem = item.itemName;

              if (brandLetter == "LB" && foodService == "N") {
                  if (brandItem.indexOf("Panettone") >= 0)  { 
                    productDivOne += 
                    '<div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">' +
                        '<div class="thumbnail">' + 
                            '<img class="scale-down-seperate-prods" src="' + item.imageURL + '" alt="' + item.itemName + '" />' +
                            '<div class="caption">' + '<br>' + 
                                '<h3 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">' + item.itemName + '</h3>' +
                                '<h4 class="group inner list-group-item-text">' + item.itemFullUPC.slice(1, -1) + ' • ' + item.itemPackSize.toLowerCase().substring(item.itemPackSize.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + '</h4>' +
                                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg showNutritionFacts" data-item-upc="' + item.itemFullUPC + '" value="itemFullUPC">Nutrition Facts</button>' +    
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                  }
                  if (brandItem.indexOf("Egg") >= 0)  { 
                    productDivTwo += 
                    '<div class="item col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">' +
                        '<div class="thumbnail">' + 
                            '<img class="scale-down-seperate-prods" src="' + item.imageURL + '" alt="' + item.itemName + '" />' +
                            '<div class="caption">' + '<br>' + 
                                '<h3 class="group inner list-group-item-heading">' + item.itemName + '</h3>' +
                                '<h4 class="group inner list-group-item-text">' + item.itemFullUPC.slice(1, -1) + ' • ' + item.itemPackSize.toLowerCase().substring(item.itemPackSize.lastIndexOf("/") + 1) + '</h4>' +
                                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg showNutritionFacts" data-item-upc="' + item.itemFullUPC + '" value="itemFullUPC">Nutrition Facts</button>' +    
                            '</div>' +
                        '</div>' +
                    '</div>';
                  }
              }
          });

          //show nutritional information on button click
          $("body").on('click', ".showNutritionFacts", function(event){

            //get passed data from other function
            var clickedItemUPC = $(this).data('item-upc');
            alert(clickedItemUPC);

            //declare variables to store data
            var servingSize = '';
            var servingPerContainer = '';
            var calories = '';
            var caloriesFat = '';
            var totalFatGrams = '';
            var totalFatPercentage = '';
            var saturatedFatGrams = '';
            var saturatedFatPercentage = '';
            var transFatGrams = '';
            var polyunsaturatedFatGrams = '';
            var monounsaturatedFatGrams = '';
            var cholesterolGrams = '';
            var cholesterolPercentage = '';
            var sodiumGrams = '';
            var sodiumPercentage = '';
            var totalCarbohydrateGrams = '';
            var totalCarbohydratePercentage = '';
            var dietaryFiberGrams = '';
            var dietaryFiberPercentage = '';
            var sugarGrams = '';
            var sugarGramsAdded = '';
            var sugarGramsAddedPercentage = '';
            var proteinGrams = '';
            var vitaminAPercentage = '';
            var vitaminCGrams = '';
            var vitaminCPercentage = '';
            var vitaminDGrams = '';
            var vitaminDPercentage = '';
            var calciumGrams = '';
            var calciumPercentage = '';
            var ironGrams = '';
            var ironPercentage = '';
            var potassiumGrams = '';
            var potassiumPercentage = '';
            var thiamineGrams = '';
            var thiaminePercentage = '';
            var riboflavinGrams = '';
            var riboflavinPercentage = '';
            var niacinGrams = '';
            var niacinPercentage = '';
            var ingredients = '';

                //comparison UPC variable
                var compareNutUPC;

                $.each(nutritional_data, function (i, item) {

                   //assign comparison UPC to itemNum
                   compareNutUPC = item.itemNum;

                   //compare product UPC in nutritional and product data
                   if (clickedItemUPC == compareNutUPC) {

                      servingSize += item.servingSize;
                      servingPerContainer += item.itemServings;
                      calories += item.itemCalories;
                      caloriesFat += item.itemCaloriesFromFat;
                      transFatGrams += item.itemTransFat + 'g';
                      polyunsaturatedFatGrams += item.itemPolyUnsatFat + 'g';
                      monounsaturatedFatGrams += item.itemMonoUnsatFat + 'g';
                      saturatedFatGrams += item.itemSaturFat + 'g';
                      saturatedFatPercentage += item.itemSaturFatPerc + '%';
                      totalFatGrams += item.itemTotalFat + 'g';
                      totalFatPercentage += item.itemTotalFatPerc + '%';
                      cholesterolGrams += item.itemCholesterol + 'mg';
                      cholesterolPercentage += item.itemCholesterolPerc + '%';
                      sodiumGrams += item.itemSodium + 'mg';
                      sodiumPercentage += item.itemSodiumPerc + '%';
                      totalCarbohydrateGrams += item.itemTotalCarb + 'g';
                      totalCarbohydratePercentage += item.itemTotalCarbPerc + '%';
                      sugarGrams += item.itemSugars + 'g';
                      sugarGramsAdded += item.itemSugarsAdded + 'g';
                      sugarGramsAddedPercentage += item.itemSugarsAddedPerc + '%';
                      dietaryFiberGrams += item.itemDietFiber + 'g';
                      dietaryFiberPercentage += item.itemDietFiberPerc + '%';
                      proteinGrams += item.itemProtein + 'g';
                      vitaminAPercentage += item.itemVitaminA + '%';
                      vitaminCPercentage += item.itemVitaminC + '%';
                      vitaminDGrams += item.itemVitaminDMeasure;
                      vitaminDPercentage += item.itemVitaminD + '%';
                      calciumGrams += item.itemCalciumMeasure;
                      calciumPercentage += item.itemCalcium + '%';
                      ironGrams += item.itemIronMeasure;
                      ironPercentage += item.itemIron + '%';
                      thiaminePercentage += item.itemThiamin + '%';
                      riboflavinPercentage += item.itemRiboflavin + '%';
                      niacinPercentage += item.itemNiacin + '%';
                      potassiumGrams += item.itemPotassium;
                      potassiumPercentage += item.itemPotassiumPerc + '%';
                      ingredients += item.itemIngredients;
                   } 
                });

                $(".servingSize").html(servingSize.replace(/\s+(?=g)/g, '').toLowerCase());
                $(".servingPerContainer").html(servingPerContainer);
                $(".calories").html(calories);
                $(".caloriesFat").html(caloriesFat);
                $(".transFatGrams").html(transFatGrams);
                $(".polyunsaturatedFatGrams").html(polyunsaturatedFatGrams);
                $(".monounsaturatedFatGrams").html(monounsaturatedFatGrams);
                $(".saturatedFatGrams").html(saturatedFatGrams);
                $(".saturatedFatPercentage").html(saturatedFatPercentage);
                $(".totalFatGrams").html(totalFatGrams);
                $(".totalFatPercentage").html(totalFatPercentage);
                $(".cholesterolGrams").html(cholesterolGrams);
                $(".cholesterolPercentage").html(cholesterolPercentage);
                $(".sodiumGrams").html(sodiumGrams);
                $(".sodiumPercentage").html(sodiumPercentage);
                $(".totalCarbohydrateGrams").html(totalCarbohydrateGrams);
                $(".totalCarbohydratePercentage").html(totalCarbohydratePercentage);
                $(".sugarGrams").html(sugarGrams);
                $(".sugarGramsAdded").html(sugarGramsAdded);
                $(".sugarGramsAddedPercentage").html(sugarGramsAddedPercentage);
                $(".dietaryFiberGrams").html(dietaryFiberGrams);
                $(".dietaryFiberPercentage").html(dietaryFiberPercentage);
                $(".proteinGrams").html(proteinGrams);
                $(".vitaminAPercentage").html(vitaminAPercentage);
                $(".vitaminCPercentage").html(vitaminCPercentage);
                $(".vitaminDGrams").html(vitaminDGrams);
                $(".vitaminDPercentage").html(vitaminDPercentage);
                $(".calciumGrams").html(calciumGrams);
                $(".calciumPercentage").html(calciumPercentage);
                $(".ironGrams").html(ironGrams);
                $(".ironPercentage").html(ironPercentage);
                $(".thiaminePercentage").html(thiaminePercentage);
                $(".riboflavinPercentage").html(riboflavinPercentage);
                $(".niacinPercentage").html(niacinPercentage);
                $(".potassiumGrams").html(potassiumGrams);
                $(".potassiumPercentage").html(potassiumPercentage);
                $(".ingredients").html(ingredients.toUpperCase());

                //determine which modal to show
                if ($('.vitaminDGrams:contains("mcg")').length > 0 && $('.calciumGrams:contains("mg")').length > 0 && $('.ironGrams:contains("mg")').length > 0) {
                    $('.nutritionPopupAlternate').modal('show');   
                } else if (servingSize == 0) {
                    $('.nutritionPopupNoInfo').modal('show');
                } else {
                    $('.nutritionPopupStandard').modal('show');
                }

          });

          //append to appropriate div
          $('#productDivOne').html(productDivOne);
          $('#productDivTwo').html(productDivTwo);

        }
      });
     //end of prod data
     }
   });
   //end of nut data
});
```

Comment: Have you tried reducing your code down?  See how small you can make it while still reproducing the problem.

Comment: I had not tried that but I just did and it looks like im making progress! Something must be wrong with the rest of the nutritional stuff. Will see what happens. I copied this code from something else I did a while back. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out.  In the future [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may help you ask questions that are more likely to get attention.  You may even find that it's a good way to work out the answers to problems that seemed unsurmountable by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Sandy i was able to minify my code and find the issue. Turns out it was looking for something that was added later from a different source code that I took, after editing the DIV it works perfectly now.